# Printing a message depending on a specific value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I'm having trouble with a project I am doing for university.
It consists on creating a diabetes risk assessment tool using html forms and javascript.

Basically there are 4 questions, each with 4 possible answers (using radio buttons, and user can only choose one answer per question).
In the end, there will be a "Calculate" button which will calculate the value of the selected answers, sum the values and display a message according the result. Here is the code for the html and javascript:

```js
let calc = document.getElementById('form');

calc.addEventListener('submit', calculateAndPrintRisk);

function calculateRisk() {
  let age = document.querySelector('input[name="age"]:checked').value;
  let bmi = document.querySelector('input[name="bmi"]:checked').value;
  let diabetes = document.querySelector('input[name="diabetes"]:checked').value;
  let diet = document.querySelector('input[name="diet"]:checked').value;
  return age + bmi + diabetes + diet;
};

function calculateAndPrintRisk(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var risk;
  var riskTotal = calculateRisk();

  if (riskTotal) {
    if (riskTotal <= 15) {
      alert("risk is low");
    } else if (riskTotal <= 25) {
      alert(risk = "medium");

    } else {
      alert(risk = "high");
    }


  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>JavaScript FMA</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    
    </head>
    <script src="diabetestool.js"> </script>
    <body>

<div id="wrapper">

  <h1>The Diabetes Risk Assesment Tool</h1>
  <div id="Options">
    <form id="form">
      <p> How old are you? </p>
      1-25 <input type="radio" name="age" value="0" checked> 26-40 <input type="radio" name="age" value="5"> 41-60 <input type="radio" name="age" value="8"> 60+ <input type="radio" name="age" value="10">

      <p> What is your BMI? </p>

      0-25 <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="0" checked> 26-30 <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="0"> 31-35 <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="9"> 35+ <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="10">

      <p> Does anybody in your family have diabetes? </p>

      No <input type="radio" name="diabetes" value="0" checked> Grandparent <input type="radio" name="diabetes" value="7"> Sibling <input type="radio" name="diabetes" value="15"> Parent <input type="radio" name="diabetes" value="15">


      <p> How would you describe your diet? </p>

      Low sugar <input type="radio" name="diet" value="0" checked> Normal sugar <input type="radio" name="diet" value="0"> Quite high sugar <input type="radio" name="diet" value="7"> High sugar <input type="radio" name="diet" value="10">


      <input type="submit" id="calculate" name="button_calculate" value="Calculate">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The code shows no errors, but does not work when I hit Calculate.

Any help would be greatly apreciated, since I am still learning javaScript.

Comment: Where did you check for errors?.. It must have been throwing some

Comment: A previous editor fixed the typo

Comment: You will need `window.onload=function() { document.querySelector("form").onsubmit=function() {calculateAndPrintRisk();return false; }` - Do NOT attach event handlers to a submit button. Make it a button or attach to the form submit event and cancel the event

Answer (score 0):

Following 2 statements must have thrown errors -

```
alert("risk is low";

alert(risk = "high";
```

Hit F12 while you execute your code on any browser. Look for console in it. You must be seeing errors there.

Comment: you are correct Rajeev. I didn't see those missing brackets. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

You don't call your function when you submit your form

You need to add and eventListener to detect when you submit your post, then cancel the Event, call your calcultateRisk function

Your event should be something like that.

```
document.getElementById('form1').addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  // do what you want
  // call your function
})
```

Comment: Any chance you could guide me on this eventListener? Should I create an eventListener in the Javascript file linking to the type="submit" input?

Comment: just edited my post with an example. If you look on google on 'Javscript event' you will find a lot of stuff

Comment: @Miguel Never attach anything to a submit button. Make it a button or attach to the form submit event

Answer (score 0):

There are a few typos, an unneccessary form ( as you dont want to submit something) and input values are generally strings, which are concatenated through the + operator. You may want to get all checked ones:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('input:checked')]
```

and reduce them to their summed up value:

```
.reduce((sum,el)=>sum+parseInt(el.value),0);
```

```js
function calculateRisk() {
  return [...document.querySelectorAll('input:checked')].reduce((sum, el) => sum + parseInt(el.value), 0);
}

function calculateAndPrintRisk() {
  var riskTotal = calculateRisk();

  if (riskTotal <= 15) {
    alert("risk is low");
  } else if (riskTotal <= 25) {
    alert("risk is medium");
  } else {
    alert("risk is high");
  }


}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <h1>The Diabetes Risk Assesment Tool</h1>
  <div id="Options">
    <p> How old are you? </p>
    1-25 <input type="radio" id="opt" name="age" value="0" checked> 26-40 <input type="radio" id="opt" name="age" value="5"> 41-60 <input type="radio" id="opt" name="age" value="8"> 60+ <input type="radio" id="opt" name="age" value="10">

    <p> What is your BMI? </p>

    0-25 <input type="radio" id="opt" name="bmi" value="0" checked> 26-30 <input type="radio" id="opt" name="bmi" value="0"> 31-35 <input type="radio" id="opt" name="bmi" value="9"> 35+ <input type="radio" id="opt" name="bmi" value="10">

    <p> Does anybody in your family have diabetes? </p>

    No <input type="radio" id="opt" name="diabetes" value="0" checked> Grandparent <input type="radio" id="opt" name="diabetes" value="7"> Sibling <input type="radio" id="opt" name="diabetes" value="15"> Parent <input type="radio" id="opt" name="diabetes"
      value="15">


    <p> How would you describe your diet? </p>

    Low sugar <input type="radio" id="opt" name="diet" value="0" checked> Normal sugar <input type="radio" id="opt" name="diet" value="0"> Quite high sugar <input type="radio" id="opt" name="diet" value="7"> High sugar <input type="radio" id="opt" name="diet"
      value="10">


    <button id="calculate" name="button_calculate" value="Calculate" onclick="calculateAndPrintRisk();">Calculate</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Note that your if else could be simplified to

```
function calculateAndPrintRisk(){
  alert("your risk is "+(riskTotal<=15?"low":(riskTotal<=25?"medium":"high")));
}
```

Comment: I suggest you do not force ES6 on a noob.

Comment: @mplungjan why not ? He then can either apply the recommended edits to his code on his own, or he can learn proper JS and loose the noob status..

Comment: Your "proper" JS needs Babel or shims to run on several browsers. Also proper JS is not using inline event handlers

Answer (score 0):

You can not use same `id` for more than one HTML element.
I have updated the code and used `querySelector` to get the `value` of radio elements.

```js
let calc = document.getElementById('form');

calc.addEventListener('submit', calculateAndPrintRisk);

function calculateRisk() {
  let age = document.querySelector('input[name="age"]:checked').value;
  let bmi = document.querySelector('input[name="bmi"]:checked').value;
  let diabetes = document.querySelector('input[name="diabetes"]:checked').value;
  let diet = document.querySelector('input[name="diet"]:checked').value;
  return age + bmi + diabetes + diet;
};

function calculateAndPrintRisk(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var risk;
  var riskTotal = calculateRisk();

  if (riskTotal) {
    if (riskTotal <= 15) {
      alert("risk is low");
    } else if (riskTotal <= 25) {
      alert(risk = "medium");

    } else {
      alert(risk = "high");
    }


  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <h1>The Diabetes Risk Assesment Tool</h1>
  <div id="Options">
    <form id="form">
      <p> How old are you? </p>
      1-25 <input type="radio" name="age" value="0" checked> 26-40 <input type="radio" name="age" value="5"> 41-60 <input type="radio" name="age" value="8"> 60+ <input type="radio" name="age" value="10">

      <p> What is your BMI? </p>

      0-25 <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="0" checked> 26-30 <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="0"> 31-35 <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="9"> 35+ <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="10">

      <p> Does anybody in your family have diabetes? </p>

      No <input type="radio" name="diabetes" value="0" checked> Grandparent <input type="radio" name="diabetes" value="7"> Sibling <input type="radio" name="diabetes" value="15"> Parent <input type="radio" name="diabetes" value="15">


      <p> How would you describe your diet? </p>

      Low sugar <input type="radio" name="diet" value="0" checked> Normal sugar <input type="radio" name="diet" value="0"> Quite high sugar <input type="radio" name="diet" value="7"> High sugar <input type="radio" name="diet" value="10">


      <input type="submit" id="calculate" name="button_calculate" value="Calculate">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would cancel the submit event too

Comment: I have tried your solution, but the code is still not working. When I hit Calculate nothing happens, no matter which options I choose in the questions. Any idea?

Comment: The code is running if you hit `Run code snippet`. So, there is no problem with my code. You may provide more information regarding the error you are facing.

Comment: @AnuragSinghBisht you are correct, if I use the Run code snippet it seems to work, but in my editor I have the correct html and javascript code and it does not work. When I hit calculate it does not show the alert box.

Comment: Have you added the `form` id. Try copy pasting my code in your code and running. I have added id of `form` with the form tag and have also remove the `id` tags from the inputs.

Comment: @AnuragSinghBisht No luck. I made sure the link to javascript file was correct and that all the tags were in the correct place. It still does not work for some reason...

Comment: Probably if there is some error in the console you can post it. Other than that it is very difficult to debug without any further information.

Comment: calc.addEventListener('submit', calculateAndPrintRisk); 
          TypeError: calc is null - This is the error that shows up on the console.

Comment: can you update your question with the latest code you are trying. It will be easier to check what's happening. Probably your  `calc = document.getElementById` is wrong.

Comment: Updated the code, but I have "calc" as calc.addEventListener (as you have in your code) and not getDocumentById.

Comment: I was talking about this line `let calc = document.getElementById('form');`. Also if you run your code now in your question, it is working fine.

Comment: The console shows up with the "TypeError: calc is null" on line 3 which is for "calc.addEventListener('submit', calculateAndPrintRisk);" and not for the let calc = document.getElementById('form');   . It still does not work on my editor but it works on the run code snippet

Comment: Here you are assigning the value to calc `let calc = document.getElementById('form');`. The value is not getting set, hence in the next line you are getting `calc is null`. Check if your `<form id="form">` is set.

Comment: @AnuragSinghBisht my <form id="form"> is correct on both the html and javascript files. I have updated my code in the beginning of the page so it is exactly how i have it on my editor at the moment. I don't understand why I still get an error on the console

Comment: Don't know man.. There has to be some difference between the code which you have in your question and your actual code. Otherwise you won't be facing the issue

Comment: @AnuragSinghBisht I found why the code was not working on my editor. But now I have another problem. If I choose the second answer for question 1, and all other questions have the first answer selected, I get a alert box with the wrong message. I should be "low" but instead the alert box shows as "high". This happens for several answers, and I can't get a "medium" alert to show up.